# GoLang mismatched types []string and string

Tags: http, go

i am trying to write http api on GoLang. When i am comparing 2 string, i am taking this error "invalid operation: a.TypeI ==  m["type"][0] (mismatched types []string and string)". How can i fix, can anyone help ?

```
func listHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    u, errUrl := url.Parse(r.URL.String())
    check(errUrl)

    m, _ := url.ParseQuery(u.RawQuery)
    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("data.json")
    check(err)

    var basedata BaseData
    err2 := json.Unmarshal(dat, &basedata)
    check(err2)

    for _, a := range basedata.Pokemons {

        if a.TypeI == m["type"][0] || a.TypeII == m["type"][0] {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "dosomething")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From the error is looks you could be comparing `[]string` to a `string`. Maybe your conditional is the issue.

Comment: I would suggest logging `a.TypeI`, `a.TypeII`, and `m["type"][0]` to see what types they are.

Comment: two both are string

Comment: Whehe is your BaseData? print those here, if your your `a.TypeI` is `[]string`, you cannot compare it with `string`. try to get your desired index first and then compare it.

Comment: @MehmetŞerefoğlu: "two both are string" No. they are not: `invalid operation: a.TypeI == m["type"][0] (mismatched types []string and string)`. They are `[]string` and `string`.

Comment: i fix my variable like that 
`for _, a := range basedata.Pokemons {

  if a.TypeI[0] == m["type"][0] {
   fmt.Fprintln(w, "dosomething")
  }
 }`
 '

but i catching a panic like that. i am still didnt find my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Go docs for the `url` package, you want [`Values.Get`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values):

```
if a.TypeI == m.Get("type") || a.TypeII == m.Get("type") {
    // do something
}
```

Furthermore, can you print the value of `r.URL.String()` for me like this:

```
fmt.Println(r.URL.String())
```